# Kivy- Where are screenshots[screenshot()] saved on Android?

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, kivy

I am having a big problem where when I use screenshot() on my android phone, I don't know where the screenshot ends up. I have looked in /storage/emulated/0/Android/data but nothing to be found. There is not even a folder for my app there.

Also, is there a way to set where the screenshots are saved? Maybe to a more logical place.

Here is my code:`

```
from random import random
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.core.window import Window


thickness = 5

class MyPaintWidget(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        color = (random(), 1, 1)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*color, mode='hsv')
            touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y), width = thickness)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if 'line' in touch.ud:
            touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]







class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        #layouts
        w = Widget()
        b = BoxLayout()
        f = FloatLayout()
        a = AnchorLayout(anchor_x= 'left', anchor_y= 'bottom')
        s = StackLayout()
        #widgets
        p = MyPaintWidget()
        cb = Button(text='Clear')
        lb = Button(pos = (150,0), text = "Large\nBrush", halign = "center")
        mb = Button(pos = (300,0), text = "Medium\nBrush", halign = "center")
        sb = Button(pos = (450,0), text = "Small\nBrush", halign = "center")
        svb = Button(pos = (600, 0), text = "Save", halign = "center")

        #adding the widgets
        w.add_widget(p)
        w.add_widget(cb)
        w.add_widget(lb)
        w.add_widget(mb)
        w.add_widget(sb)
        w.add_widget(svb)
        #w.export_to_png('ScreenShot.png')



        #bindings
        def clear_canvas(obj):
            p.canvas.clear()
        cb.bind(on_release=clear_canvas)

        def large_brush(obj):
            global thickness
            thickness = 15
        lb.bind(on_release=large_brush)

        def medium_brush(obj):
            global thickness
            thickness = 10
        mb.bind(on_release=medium_brush)

        def small_brush(obj):
            global thickness
            thickness = 5
        sb.bind(on_release=small_brush)


        def Screenshot(obj):
            global Screenshotnum
            Window.screenshot(name="Screenshot.png")

        svb.bind(on_release=Screenshot)


        return w


if __name__ == '__main__':
   MyPaintApp().run()`
```

Disregard the "export_to_png" part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot is saved to the path you specify, in this case just a filename in the current directory, which is probably somewhere in `/data/data` and won't be accessible to other applications unless you have root access. You can check what the directory is within your script, probably with `os.getcwd()`.

You can probably just pass the external storage filepath you want to save to as the argument for `screenshot`. In general, you could query the android api with pyjnius to get the filepath android recommends your application should use.

Comment: The current directory will actually be the app's sdcard directory - `/sdcard/org.kivy.launcher/screenshot0001.png`

Comment: You should also update your answer to note that the screenshot filename will ALWAYS include a number - so if you pass 'MyScreen.png' as the filename it will automatically become 'MyScreen0001.png' (or whatever the appropriate number is).

Comment: I used buildozer to make an APK, so I did not use Kivy launcher

Comment: Can i get an example of the os module? Also an example that can relate to my case using pyjnius? I learn better when I look at examples. I am a little confused about it after reading the docs on kivy's website.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshot